# Converting traditional Japanese era year into Gregorian year

Tags: php, internationalization

> The traditional Japanese calendar consists of eras based on the
>   reigning emperors. The imperial date format is required for some
>   government documents and applications. For example, until Jan 1, 2002,
>   the Japanese patent office used emperor dates.

[more info](http://www.i18nguy.com/l10n/emperor-date.html)

I would like to make a conversion between the traditional Japanese calendar and the Gregorian one.

Using the date format from here:

http://www.icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/classSimpleDateFormat.html#details

And with the [Internationalization Functions in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php).

I developed this script:

```
/**
 * Convert japanese year (traditional) to gregorian calendar
 * 
 * @author  Gerard Brull <gbblanes@gmail.com>
 * @version 0.1 29/01/2015 (in gregorian calendar :P)
 */

if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0', '<')) {
    die('we need php 5.3.0 or later');
}

if (!class_exists('IntlDateFormatter')) {
    die('we need php_intl extension.');
}

//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// CONVERT JAPANESE YEAR ERA IN GREGORIAN CALENDAR
//----------------------------------------------------------------------


$cal = IntlCalendar::createInstance(null,'ja_JP@calendar=japanese');

//You can find the era number here: http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=ja_JP&d_=en&calendar=japanese
$cal->set(IntlCalendar::FIELD_ERA, 235); //Heisei (平成)

$cal->set(IntlCalendar::FIELD_YEAR, 27); //year of the era
$cal->clear(IntlCalendar::FIELD_HOUR_OF_DAY);
$cal->clear(IntlCalendar::FIELD_MINUTE);
$cal->clear(IntlCalendar::FIELD_SECOND);
$cal->clear(IntlCalendar::FIELD_MILLISECOND);

echo 'Year in Gregorian calendar ' . $cal->get(IntlCalendar::FIELD_YEAR_WOY) . ' | ' ;
//Result: Year in Gregorian calendar 2015 | 



//----------------------------------------------------------------------
// CONVERT GREGORIAN CALENDAR (NOW) IN JAPANESE YEAR ERA
//----------------------------------------------------------------------

$now = new DateTime();

$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ja_JP@calendar=japanese',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Madrid',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    'Gy' //Age and year (regarding the age)
);

echo 'Age in Japanese: '. $formatter->format($now);
//Result: Age in Japanese: 平成27
```

However, if you look on my code, you can see that I need the number of the Japanese emperor to make it work.

And i would like to know if it's possible to convert this string:

```
'平成27'
```

Into the correct Gregorian year (2015) directly.

I know I can do it by making an Array of Strings => EmperorNumber but I would like to know if there is a better proper way.

Thanks in advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to use `IntlDateFormatter::parse`:

```
<?php
$formatter = new IntlDateFormatter(
    'ja_JP@calendar=japanese',
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    IntlDateFormatter::FULL,
    'Europe/Madrid',
    IntlDateFormatter::TRADITIONAL,
    'Gy' //Age and year (regarding the age)
);
$r = $formatter->format(strtotime('2012-01-01 Europe/Madrid'));
echo "Age in Japanese: $r\n";
$time = $formatter->parse($r);
$gregCalendar = IntlCalendar::createInstance('Europe/Madrid', 'ja_JP');
$gregCalendar->setTime($time * 1000);
$r2 = IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($gregCalendar, 'Gy');
echo "And back: $r2\n";
```

gives:

```
Age in Japanese: 平成24
And back: AD2012
```

Comment: Can you explain me this line:  $gregCalendar->setTime($time * 1000);
Why "* 1000" ?

Comment: @GerardBrull It's because unfortunately the ->parse implementation divides the result it gets from ICU by 1000 and truncates that to an integer, while `IntlCalendar::setTime` preserves the ICU semantics.